# What does wordpress search, search?

Tags: search

I just realized in testing, it appears worpress search is not matching my search term "php" with any post's tagged with "php" or in a category of "php" unless php is in the title or body, is that all the search searches for?

Answer (score 4):

yes, WordPress search only searches title or post content. There are a few plugins that extend search to taxonomies, [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) is one.

EDIT - The query WordPress produces for default search:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%')
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%test%')))
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment')
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_author = 1
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: thanks, ill just have to remember to include the tags/category term somewhere in the content

Comment: I think what @Milo says is not correct.
Default search can search taxonomies and custom fields. Check this analysis here:
https://gist.github.com/2023628

Comment: @p.a. - you can obviously query taxonomies and custom fields but the actual query WordPress performs when you do a search does not include those things. see edit above for SQL WordPress produces when you perform a search.

Comment: @Milo I lost you; can Wordpress search for custom taxonomies and custom fields via Wp-Query or not? This is important for my dev plans. Thanks

Comment: @p.a. - you can't do a full pattern match search of everything simultaneously without directly modifying the query via filters like [`posts_join`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join) and [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where)